# How can I get Core Data transaction logs downloaded from iCloud even if App is not running

Tags: core-data, icloud

How can I make sure that any iCloud Core Data transaction logs are automatically downloaded to a device, even if the App is not active ?

Currently it seems new transaction logs are only downloaded when the app becomes active, is there anyway I can get a device to download these as soon as they become available?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. On iOS, transaction data is only downloaded on demand. You create that demand in your app by adding the persistent store while using iCloud configuration options. If the app isn't running, there's no demand, and if there's no demand then there's no download. If you need this, literally the only option is to file a bug with Apple and hope that they change this in some future version of iOS. I wouldn't bet on them doing it, though-- it would almost certainly be rejected due to some combination of the effect on battery, monthly data transfer quotas, or device storage space.

Comment: What about running in the background, might that trigger demand? I was thinking of doing a metadata query and setting the download flag on the transaction logs.

Comment: I'm not sure whether running in the background triggers continued updates. I doubt that messing with metadata flags on the transaction logs is going to be useful.

Comment: It seems to get the logs downloaded fine, so it works if the application is active but no core data stack built yet. Just can't seem to get the download to work while the app is in the background.  My code runs to set the download flag but the OS does not seem to perform the download.